# Java : different init parameters to same servlet based on different URL patteren

Tags: java, servlets, web.xml

Is it possible to send default parameters to same servlet but different on url-patterns.
Like I have one servlet `/Add` different url patterns like `/AddPerson` or `/AddEmplyoee` will map to `/Add` servlet. But i want to pass some parameters when /Add servlet is called. Like when `/AddPerson` is called send type = 1 to `/Add` Servlet. When `/AddEmplyoee` is called send type = 2 to `/Add` Servlet.
I know that I can pass init parameters to `/Add` servlet using `<init-param>` tag.
Is it possible to do this or I want to write different servlet for each different operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The Servlet life-cycle does not permit the Servlet to re-init every request (by parameters). Per [The Java EE Tutorial - Initializing a Servlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnafu.html) (emphasis added),

> After the web container loads and instantiates the servlet class and before it delivers requests from clients, the web container initializes the servlet. To customize this process to allow the servlet to read persistent configuration data, initialize resources, and perform any other **one-time activities**, you override the init method of the Servlet interface.

As for mapping the request uri to a parameter, you could certainly do it yourself (using a Map and the request path as the key).

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**. It think it is possible.
If (in the web.xml) you define the servlet *AddPerson* (with servlet-class=*com.foo.Add*) and a servlet *AddEmplyoee* (with the **same** servlet-class) than you can use different init parameter. E.g.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AddPerson</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.foo.Add</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>myParam</param-name>
        <param-value>MyVal1</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AddEmplyoee</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.foo.Add</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>myParam</param-name>
        <param-value>MyVal2</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

with following mappings:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AddPerson</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/addperson</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AddEmployee</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/addemployee</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

You may correct me, if I am wrong, but I think, that this will end up in TWO individual servlets (both based on the same class).